# Dynamic Associative Array Creation in Javascript from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

It sounds a lot more complicated than it really is.

So in Perl, you can do something like this:

```
foreach my $var (@vars) {
  $hash_table{$var->{'id'}} = $var->{'data'};
}
```

I have a JSON object and I want to do the same thing, but with a javascript associative array in jQuery.

I've tried the following:

```
hash_table = new Array();

$.each(data.results), function(name, result) {
  hash_table[result.(name).extra_info.a] = result.(name).some_dataset;
});
```

Where data is a JSON object gotten from a $.getJSON call.  It looks more or less like this (my JSON syntax may be a little off, sorry):

```
{
  results:{
    datasets_a:{
      dataset_one:{
        data:{
          //stuff
        }
        extra_info:{
          //stuff
        }
      }
      dataset_two:{
         ...
      }
      ...
    }
    datasets_b:{
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

But every time I do this, firebug throws the following error:

"XML filter is applied to non-xml data"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use the JSON response as an associative array. So you should be able to go directly in and use the JSON.

Assuming you received the above example:

```
$('result').innerHTML = data['results']['dataset_a']['dataset_two']['data'];
// Or the shorter form:
$('result').innerHTML = data.results.dataset_a.dataset_two.data;
```

Understand that I haven't tested this, but it's safer to use the square brackets with a variable than it is to use parenthesis plus the name with the dot accessor.

Your example is failing because of some convoluted logic I just caught.

```
$.each(data.results), function(name, result) {
     hash_table[result.(name).extra_info.a] = result.(name).some_dataset;
});
```

Now, the foreach loop goes through the variable `data.results` to find the internal elements at a depth of 1.  The item it finds is given to the lambda with the key of the item.  AKA, the first result will be `name = "datasets_a" item = object`.  Following me so far?  Now you access the returned hash, the object in `item`, as though it has the child key in `name` ... "datasets_a".  But wait, this **is** the object!

If all else fails... write your result JSON into a text field dynamically and ensure it is formatted properly.

Comment: in your last code block, it should be function(name, result).  name being the key, result being the value of that key.

Comment: I accepted the first part, since it turns out that I could just access the json object directly.  Stupid of me to not realize that in the first place.

Comment: Alright, in MooTools it's reversed so I'm used to that model.

Comment: +1 for telling me `data['results']['dataset_a']['dataset_two']['data'];` way of calling json objects.

Comment: the square bracket are accessors which can be used on arrays `arr = [1]; arr[0]` and objects `obj = { foo : 'hello world'}; obj['foo']; x = 'foo'; obj[x]`

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to change an array into another array ?-)

-- why not simply access the data, if you want to simplify or filter, you can traverse the arrays of the object directly !-)

Answer (score 0):

This works. Just dump it into a script block to test.

```
    d = {
      'results':{
       'datasets_a':{
          'dataset_one':{
            'data':{
              'sample':'hello'
            },
            'extra_info':{
              //stuff
            }
          },
      'dataset_two':{
            ///
          }
          ///
    },
        'datasets_b':{
         ///
        }
      }
}
alert(d.results.datasets_a.dataset_one.data.sample)
```

I hope this pasted in correctly. This editor doesn't like my line breaks in code.

```
d = {
  'results':{
   'datasets_a':{
      'dataset_one':{
        'data':{
          'sample':'hello'
        },
        'extra_info':{
          //stuff
        }
      },
      'dataset_two':{
        ///
      }
      ///
    },
    'datasets_b':{
     ///
    }
  }
};

alert(d.results.datasets_a.dataset_one.data.sample)
```